# wireless card's name is strange

Tags: wireless

My wireless card's name is strange, and I can't connect to the internet though I have connected to my router.

```
ro0t@root:~$iwconfig
wlx00e0d00699b IEEE 802.11 ESSID:off/any
                     Mode:Managed Access Point:Not-Associate     Tx-Power=20 dBm (etc etc....)
```

Comment: Please provide more information: Computer brand name and model, Version of Ubuntu, and all possible information about the wireless card. Also, please tell us *how* you have tried to connect to the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Your wireless interface name is 'weird' because of predictable network naming: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

You may have better luck connecting if you make a small change to Network Manager. Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

At the bottom of this file, copy and paste the following:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Proofread carefully, save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and close (Ctrl+x) the text editor. Restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Any improvement?

Comment: He may haven't Internet for a lot of reasons. Why [setting a fixed MAC address](https://blogs.gnome.org/thaller/2016/08/26/mac-address-spoofing-in-networkmanager-1-4-0/) would be the cause?

Comment: @PabloBianchi Because of this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1681513